# Pass FormControl to Outside FormBuilder in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

We are creating a wrapper on Angular Material Select. How do I pass FormControl from Inner Component (Material dropdown select) to an outside Parent Component Formbuilder? Trying to figure out the syntax, and want to not utilize ControlValueAccessor if possible.

**Child Material Dropdown Select:**

**TS:**

```
@Input() formControlnput = new FormControl('',[Validators.min(1)]])
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="dropdown-cont">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
            <mat-select
                [formControl]="formControlInput"  // See here
                [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
                (selectionChange)="selectedItemChanged($event)"
                >
                <mat-option [value]="defaultItem[txtValue]">{{defaultItem[txtField]}}</mat-option>
                <mat-option
                    *ngFor="let item of listItems"
                    [value]="item[txtValue]"
                >
                {{item[txtField]}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

**Parent Component:**

```
this.outerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'customerName':[null,[Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  'customerPhone': [null, [Validators.maxLength(15)]],
  'formControlInput': [null,[Validators.required]], // <--- Need this from inner component
```

How do I pass the inner child component from Material dropdown select, the outside formBuilder?

Comment: The correct way of building that would be to use a ValueControlAccessor. If you don't want to deal with all the boilerplate you can use ngx-sub-form https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form to handle that for you :)

Comment: we are trying to avoid ValueControlAccessor, since we are doing a double wrapper on a material dropdown in long term

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59302396/angular-use-child-component-form-in-parent-component-nested-form?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: why would you avoid ValueControlAccessor? making a wrapper on a form control should definitely use that IMO

Comment: hi @Abhishek  can you edit the answer, since my form is mixed with another parent form having its own stuff, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `@Output()` whit an `EventEmitter`, and just `emit(formControl)` in the child component `ngOnInit()` method.

Comment: Sure, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1rnwq?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts

Comment: well still need to see it link to outside formbuilder

Comment: I don't understand clearly what you want. See my example again, here have an `ngAfterViewChecked()` where you can see the form value which is updated when you type in the input.

Comment: can you have a Formbuilder in the parent component? and make the child attached the parent formbuilder control, see my question example thanks

Comment: See the example again, I`m not sure what you want but i think this is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1rnwq?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts