# Angular Parent Form with Child Form Component, how to Let Child Know when Parent is submitted?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular11

I am using a Parent Form with a Child Component Form as in this manner. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310301/15435022

How do I let the Child Component know when Parent Form has button Ng submitted? The parentForm variable is in child component as variable. Is there a way, I can tell with parentFormGroup as an event?

When the child form knows, I want to calculate some intricate values (not in the form), and send them to the parentComponent.

**Parent Component:**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
       'customerName': [null, [Validators.required]],
       'phoneNumber': [null, [Validators.required]],
    })

 <form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-child [form]="parentForm"></app-child>
    <button type="submit">Purchase</button>
 </form>
```

**Child Component:**

Need to know in this component, when parentForm is submitted.

```
@Input() parentForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.parentForm.addControl('address', new FormControl(Validators.required));
    this.parentForm.addControl('city', new FormControl(Validators.required));
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `@ViewChild` and get the child component reference and run its method.

Example

```js
//Child component
runThisWhenParentFormSubmitted(parentForm: FormGroup) {
 parentForm.addControl('address', new FormControl(Validators.required));
 parentForm.addControl('city', new FormControl(Validators.required));
}
```

```html
<!-- Parent Component -->
<form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-child></app-child>
    <button type="submit">Purchase</button>
</form>
```

```js
//Parent component
parentForm: FormGroup;
@ViewChild(AppChildComponent) appChildComponent: AppChildComponent;

onSubmit() {
 this.appChildComponent.runThisWhenParentFormSubmitted(this.parentForm);
}
```

[Working Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoking-child-method-from-parent)

---

**Option 2**
Use `@Input` as observable and subscribe in child component

Example

```js
//Parent component
parentForm: FormGroup;
parentFormSubject$ = new Subject<FormGroup>();
parentFormObservable$ = this.parentFormSubject$.asObservable();

onSubmit() {
  this.parentFormSubject$.next(this.parentForm);
}

//Make sure to complete the observable to avoid memory leaks
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.parentFormSubject$.next();
    this.parentFormSubject$.complete();
}
```

```html
<!-- Parent Component -->
<form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-child [form]="parentFormObservable$"></app-child>
    <button type="submit">Purchase</button>
</form>
```

```js
//Child component
@Input() form: Observable<FormGroup>;
subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.form) {
    this.subscription = this.form.subscribe(formGroup => {
      console.log("Child", formGroup);
    });
  }
}

//Make sure to unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks
ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

[Working Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoking-child-method-from-parent-2)

---

**Option 3**
As already explained by @chellappan not possible for `formGroup` since it does not contain such event or property.

What you can do is create one more `@Input` specifically for submit event, **This is bit hacky solution**

Example

```js
//Child component
@Input() parentForm: FormGroup;

@Output() parentFormSubmittedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
@Input() set parentFormSubmitted(isSubmitted: boolean) {
  if (isSubmitted) {
    console.log(this.parentForm);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.parentFormSubmittedChange.next(false);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Parent Component -->
<form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-child [parentForm]="parentForm" [(parentFormSubmitted)]="parentFormSubmitted"></app-child>
    <button type="submit">Purchase</button>
</form>
```

```js
//Parent component
onSubmit() {
  this.parentFormSubmitted = true;
}
```

As you can see above in the child component, we are again setting `parentFormSubmitted` as false using `eventEmitter`. This is because `@Input`'s setter will only invoke if the value is changed.

I also wrapped that in `setTimeout` as it was throwing `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

[Working Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoking-child-method-from-parent-3)

Comment: @mattsmith5 Answer updated, added one more option

Comment: quick question, can I also use Getters Setters method with the @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;, and how do Check for NgOnsubmit here? is that possible? thanks !

Answer (score 5):

You can inject [FormGroupDirective](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective) inside child component then subscribe ngOnSubmit event inside child component to listen parent form submission.

**child.component.ts**

```
 constructor(private fg: FormGroupDirective){
    this.fg.ngSubmit.subscribe(()=>{
      console.log('listen submit');
    })
  }
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-form-with-child-form-component-how-to-let-child?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: Not possible. FormGroup class does not have submitted property and ngOnSubmit event, FormGroupDirective only have these onSumit event and submitted events